# Vue3 datepicker : disable left and right arrows

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs3, vuepic-vue-datepicker

I am using [@vuepic/vue3datepicker](https://vue3datepicker.com/) and I would like to disable or hide the next and previous arrows to prevent the user checking data outside the current month:

[image]

I did not find a useful prop to use for this purpose.

I tried the [:hide-navigation](https://vue3datepicker.com/props/general-configuration/#hide-navigation)  prop but it did not work.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: It looks like there's no prop/slot to hide these arrows, I think it's better to use the `allowed-dates` prop to allow the current month dates only

Comment: Can you create a snippet or a fiddle? It's difficult to experiment with an image.

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Thank you for the hint, I tried it but the navigation arrows are still functioning

Comment: There seems to be slots to override the content of the button (but that’s not good as the button will still be accessible with the keyboard), although there’s also a slot to override the whole header, see https://github.com/Vuepic/vue-datepicker/blob/main/src/VueDatePicker/components/DatePicker/DpHeader.vue#L3

Comment: The slot is a possible solution but a link to it's [documentation](https://vue3datepicker.com/slots/components/#month-year) would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arrows can be disabled if the mininum and maximum dates fall within the current month and [prevent-min-max-navigation](https://vue3datepicker.com/props/calendar-configuration/#prevent-min-max-navigation) prop is used.

```html
<VueDatePicker
  v-model="date"
  :min-date="minDate"
  :max-date="maxDate"
  prevent-min-max-navigation
  hide-offset-dates
/>
```

```js
<script setup>
import { ref, computed } from 'vue'
import { startOfMonth, endOfMonth } from 'date-fns'

const date = ref(new Date())
const minDate = computed(() => startOfMonth(new Date()))
const maxDate = computed(() => endOfMonth(new Date()))
</script>
```

There's also the [disable-month-year-select](https://vue3datepicker.com/props/calendar-configuration/#disable-month-year-select) prop that will hide the header of the calendar picker which includes the arrows.